# Drools Rule for nested array

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am new to Drools. I am converting xml file to Java POJO classes using JAXB and based on xml data (converted Java POJO ) applying drools rules on those data.

Below are the POJO's

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ADI")
public class ADI {
    private Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    private Asset asset=new Asset();
//Getters and Setter
}
@XmlRootElement(name="Asset")
public class Asset {
    
    private Metadata[] metadata;
    private Asset[] asset;
    private String content;
//Getters and Setter
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Metadata")
public class Metadata {
    private AMS ams= new AMS();
    private AppData[] appData;
//Getters and Setter
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "App_Data")
public class AppData {

    private String app;
    private String name;
    private String value;
//Getters and Setter
}
```

Based on above POJO's, need to create rule like below (i know this is wrong but just giving idea what i am trying to achieve). There are multiple AppData array which contain name field as "Category" and value field starts with "Premium Channels". There can be n number of instances and need to update all those instances.

```
 rule "GCI RULE for Replacing  APP_Category from Premiums Channels to Premiums/Showtime/SD/"
    when
       $adi : ADI()
       $metadata: Metadata($appDataArray : appData !=null , $appData : appData, $name : name=="Category", $value : value.startswith("Premium Channels")) from $adi.metadata
        
    then
        System.out.println("Rule executed 3");
        $appData.setValue("Premiums/Showtime/SD/");
        update($adi);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are multiple AppData array which contain name field as "Category" and value field starts with "Premium Channels". There can be n number of instances and need to update all those instances.

You're actually somewhat close with your attempt. The only part you didn't get quite right was interacting with the individual items in the `appData` array.

Basically what we need to do is to find all of the AppData items that meet your criteria (name="Category", value startsWith "Premium Channels"), and then update them. We can do this with a `collect`.

```
rule "GCI RULE for Replacing  APP_Category from Premiums Channels to Premiums/Showtime/SD/"
when
  $adi : ADI( $metadata: metadata != null )
  Metadata( $appDataArray : appData !=null ) from $metadata
  $items: ArrayList() from collect( 
      AppData( name == "Category", value str[startsWith] "PremiumChannels") from $appDataArray
  )
then
  System.out.println("Rule executed 3");
  for( AppData $appData : $items ) {
    $appData.setValue("Premiums/Showtime/SD/");
  }
  update($adi);
end
```

(Note depending on your setup, you might need to use an indexed for-loop instead of a foreach; I trip over that problem sometimes when using mvel dialect and certain versions of Drools.)

Another way you could do this would be to get the individual items out of the array on the left-hand side and update them one-by-one on the right-hand-side ... the side effect of this would be you'd call this rule multiple times. The overhead of this is probably non-trivial in a production setting.

```
rule "GCI RULE for Replacing  APP_Category from Premiums Channels to Premiums/Showtime/SD/"
when
  $adi : ADI( $metadata: metadata != null )
  Metadata( $appDataArray : appData !=null) from $metadata
  $appData: AppData( name == "Category", 
                     value str[startsWith] "PremiumChannels" ) from $appDataArray
then
  System.out.println("Rule executed 3");
  $appData.setValue("Premiums/Showtime/SD/");
  update($adi);
end
```

This variation will fire the rule once per AppData item in the array that doesn't already match the target value.

Comment: I tried the above rule but while loading the server giving runtime exception as field reader does not exist for declaration name and value. I am using POJO classes as defined in question. Any issues you can see

Comment: Those are from your original rule, so I had assumed 'name' and 'value' are fields on Metadata. Are they fields on AppData?

Comment: Yes, They are part of AppData. Is it something i am doing it wrong here. If you can see my POJO class above for AppData,  shows fields name and value are part of AppData.

Comment: I updated the examples in my answer for those fields being part of AppData. Your initial attempt at the rule made it look like you were checking those fields on Metadata.